# How to move this circle using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I'm a newbie in HTML, CSS, and Javascript.
I'm trying to make a little circle that move right 10px **every** time it is clicked. I try by writing this short code :

```js
function moveit() {
  document.getElementById("circle").style.cx += "10px";
};
```

```html
<svg width="500px">
  <circle id="circle" cx="10px" cy="10px" r="5px" onclick="moveit()" />
</svg>
```

By writing the code above, I'm trying to add 10px to the **cx** every time the circle is clicked. But it seems fail to add 10px to the **cx**. I need to know how to do that in the right way. Thank you!

Comment: I know you've accepted my answer, but I've edited it with some _potentially_ more helpful code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're editing an attribute, not a CSS style.

You want to use `getAttribute` to get the current value, and then set it again with `setAttribute`.

```js
function moveit() {
  var objCircle = document.getElementById("circle");
  var intCX = parseInt(objCircle.getAttribute('cx'));
  objCircle.setAttribute('cx', intCX + 10 + 'px');
};
```

```html
<svg width="500px">
  <circle id="circle" cx="10px" cy="10px" r="5px" onclick="moveit(this)" />
</svg>
```

#### Edit

If you're running this function against multiple elements, then it is perhaps best done by assigning a class to your moveable elements and then using a listener. Also Robert Longson's idea to use the SVG DOM is far superior to using setAttribute so I've included that too.

```js
function MoveRight(objSVG, intVal) {
  objSVG.cx.baseVal.value += intVal;
};

var objMovers = document.querySelectorAll('.moveme'); // Get a list of the nodes with the moveme class
Array.prototype.forEach.call(objMovers, function(element, index) { // Loop through each of these element nodes
  element.addEventListener('click', function() { // Apply a click listener
    MoveRight(this, 10); // Run the MoveRight function and push this element and the amount through.
  });
});
```

```html
<svg width="500px">
  <circle class="moveme" id="circle" cx="10px" cy="10px" r="5px" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `cx` is an `attribute` of the HTML element. As such, use `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` to retrieve and assign attribute values accordingly. In your case, to retrieve the value:

```
var cx = document.getElementById("circle").getAttribute("cx");
```

Also, I have added some Regex which strips non-numerical characters from the `cx` attribute and converts it to an `int` before incrementing it by 10:

```
cx = parseInt(cx.replace(/\D/g,'')) + 10;
```

And finally, assign the new attribute value to the element:

```
document.getElementById("circle").setAttribute("cx", cx);
```

Putting it all together:

```
<script>
    function moveit() {
        var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
        var cx = circle.getAttribute("cx");
        cx = parseInt(cx.replace(/\D/g,'')) + 10;
        circle.setAttribute("cx", cx);
    };
</script>
<body>
    <svg width="500px">
        <circle id="circle" cx="10px" cy="10px" r="5px" onclick="moveit()"/>
    </svg>
</body>
```

[Working JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p16jp2v7/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SVG DOM to do this, that way you can avoid all the get/set attribute stuff and use += as you wanted to. All the complication about removing units and converting to/from strings is also avoided.

```js
function moveit() {
  document.getElementById("circle").cx.baseVal.value += 10;
};
```

```html
<svg width="500px">
  <circle id="circle" cx="10px" cy="10px" r="5px" onclick="moveit()" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `setAttribute`, eg:

```
x = 10;
moveit = function() {
    x = x + 10
    document.getElementById("circle").setAttribute("cx", x);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejtef6fx/

Example with `getAttribute`:

```
moveit = function() {
    var svg = document.getElementById("circle")
    var x = parseInt(svg.getAttribute("cx"))
    x = x + 10
    svg.setAttribute("cx", x)
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejtef6fx/1/

Use parseInt or parseFloat to ensure the value returned is a number before you add 10 onto it.

Comment: Use `getAttribute` for the initial value of x?

Comment: yep, but use parseInt or parseFloat to ensure it is a number before you add 10, eg `x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("circle").getAttribute("x"));`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function moveit() {
    var cx = document.getElementById("circle").getAttribute("cx");
    cx = cx.replace('px', ''); // remove px
    cx = parseInt(cx); // convert to int
    cx += 10; // add 10
    cx = cx.toString() + 'px'; // append px
    document.getElementById("circle").setAttribute("cx", cx);
};
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tyeLqj32/).

Answer (score 1):

cx is an attribute not a CSS property. here is how to increment it on click:

```
function moveit() {
    //get current cx value
  var cx = document.getElementById("circle").getAttribute('cx');

    //remove the 'px' part
  var cxVal = Number(cx.substring(0, cx.length - 2));

    //increment cx value by 10
    cxVal+=10;

    //set value again
  document.getElementById("circle").setAttribute('cx', cxVal+'px');
};
```

a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qmchLqtq/

Answer (score -1):

Hope this may help you :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.moveit = function(elementID) {
                var currentElement = document.getElementById(elementID);
                    currentElement.setAttribute('cx', parseInt(currentElement.getAttribute('cx'), 10) + 10 + 'px');
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="500px">
             <circle id="circle" cx="10px" cy="10px" r="5px" onclick="moveit(this.id)"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run this I get currentElement is null in the browser console and nothing happens.

Comment: <circle id="circle" cx="10px" cy="10px" r="5px" onclick="moveit(this.id)"/>   I forgot to edit the html tag

Comment: You might want to change it to `moveit(this)` and just replace `elementID` with `currentElement`

Comment: No, it doesn't. It sets cx to 10px10 and then 10px1010 and then 10px101010 because you're not converting from strings to floats properly.